# Subfloat caption problem

Tags: subfloats

I have two figures side-by-side as in Figure[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3diK.png).

This is the current situation using the following code:

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \subfloat[Overall architecture]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{images/Graphiti/graphiti_architecture}
    } \hfill{} \subfloat[Detail of the diagram type  agent\label{fig:Diagram-type-agent}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{images/Graphiti/diagram-type-agent-new}  
 }

 \protect\caption{Graphiti architecture\label{fig:Graphiti-architecture}}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

As you can see they are not vertically aligned. Googling for a solution I've found this code:

```
 \newsavebox{\tempbox}
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/Graphiti/graphiti_architecture}}
    \subfloat[Graphiti Architecture]{\usebox{\tempbox}\label{sparse}}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[Detail diagarm type agent]{\vbox to \ht\tempbox{%
            \vfil
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/Graphiti/diagram-type-agent-new}
            \vfil}\label{full}}%
    \caption{Graphiti Architecture [ref]}\label{schematic}
 \end{figure}
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image]

It is exactly what I want, but the second caption is wrong. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Thanks David for the answer. Honestly Im a newbie with latex.

Comment: I've edited my post. Maybe now the question is a little bit clearer :)

Comment: You guess is correct @DavidCarlisle

Comment: the subfig guess or the hsize guess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18896/discussion-between-user3727540-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `\hbox` like

```
\vfil
\hbox to 0.45\textwidth{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/Graphiti/diagram-type-agent-new}}
            \vfil}
```

Make `to 0.45\textwidth` same as that in `\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]`

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}

 \newsavebox{\tempbox}
 \begin{figure}[H]
    \sbox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth,height=8cm]{images/Graphiti/graphiti_architecture}}
    \subfloat[Graphiti Architecture]{\usebox{\tempbox}\label{sparse}}%
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Detail diagarm type agent]{\vbox to \ht\tempbox{%
            \vfil
            \hbox to 0.45\textwidth{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{images/Graphiti/diagram-type-agent-new}
            }
            \vfil}\label{full}}%
    \caption{Graphiti Architecture [ref]}\label{schematic}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]